# PineScript - lookahead_on / off

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I'm having trouble understanding the trading view documents, so I wanted to know: I use the request.security and lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on functions in my script.
Are they compatible with backtesting? In the other words, I wanted to make sure that they don't use futures data.

My script :

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='Strat des enfers', shorttitle='S', overlay=true, pyramiding=0,
initial_capital=100000, currency=currency.USD)
useHA = input(false, title='Use Heikken Ashi Candles')
useAltTF = input(true, title='Use Alt Timeframe')
tf = input('60', title='Alt Timeframe')

zigzag() =>
    var float _direction = na
    var float _zigzag = na
    if na(_direction[1])
        _direction := 0 
    _isUp = close >= open
    _isDown = close <= open
    _highest = ta.highest(2)
    _lowest = ta.lowest(2)
    _direction := _isUp[1] and _isDown ? -1 : _isDown[1] and _isUp ? 1 : nz(_direction[1])
    _zigzag := _isUp[1] and _isDown and _direction[1] != -1 ? _highest : _isDown[1] and _isUp and _direction[1] != 1 ? _lowest : na

_ticker = useHA ? ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid) : syminfo.tickerid
sz = useAltTF ? (ta.change(time(tf)) != 0 ? request.security(_ticker, tf, zigzag(), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on) : na) : zigzag()

plot(sz, title='zigzag', color=color.black, linewidth=2)
```